# XSD Schema 1.1 validation in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I have figured out how to validate an XML file using an XSD schema in PHP using this code, but it appears the processing is done using XSD version 1.0.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xmlString);

$isValid = $dom->schemaValidate($xsdFile);
```

For my case, I need the XSD file to be treated as version 1.1. The main reason for this is that I want to use:

```
<xs:all>
   <xs:element type="xs:string" name="br" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   <xs:element type="linkType" name="link" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:all>
```

Notice the `maxOccurs="unbounded"` which can only be used inside `<xs:all>` with version 1.1. In version 1.0, the `maxOccurs` can only be 0 or 1.

PHP fails with the generic error:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema
```

Answer (score 2):

DOMDocument::schemaValidate use Libxml. Libxml does not support XSD 1.1.